# Problem with API Query Python

Tags: soql, api, query, python

I am trying to create a query with python using a IN clause :

```
def sf_api_call(action, parameters = {}, method = 'get', data = {}, keys = {}): # pylint: disable=dangerous-default-value
"""
Helper function to make calls to Salesforce REST API.
Parameters: action (the URL), URL params, method (get, post or patch), data for POST/PATCH.
"""
session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect = 3, backoff_factor = 0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries = retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + keys['access_token']
}
if method == 'get':
    #r = requests.request(method, keys['instance_url']+action, headers=headers, params=parameters, timeout=500) #pylint: disable=line-too-long, invalid-name
    r = session.get(keys['instance_url']+action, headers=headers, params=parameters, timeout=500)
#elif method in ['post', 'patch']:
elif method == 'post':
    #r = requests.request(method, keys['instance_url']+action, headers=headers, json=data, params=parameters, timeout=500) #pylint: disable=line-too-long, invalid-name
    r = session.post(keys['instance_url']+action, headers=headers, json=data, params=parameters, timeout=500)
elif method == 'patch':
    r = session.patch(keys['instance_url']+action, headers=headers, json=data, params=parameters, timeout=500) #pylint: disable=line-too-long, invalid-name
else:
    # other methods not implemented in this example
    raise ValueError('Method should be get or post or patch.')
print('Debug: API %s call: %s' % (method, r.url) ) #pylint: disable=consider-using-f-string
if r.status_code < 300: #pylint: disable=no-else-return
    if method=='patch':
        return None
    return r.json()
else:
    raise Exception('API error when calling %s : %s %s' % (r.url, r.content, r)) #pylint: disable=consider-using-f-string

COMMENT_IDS = ",".join(f"'{w}'" for w in lst_ids)
get_comments = sf_api_call('/services/data/v53.0/query/', {
               'q': 'SELECT Id, Name, frm_LastModifiedDate__c, frm_ExternalCommentId__c, frm_ExternalCommentReplyId__c, frm_ExtenalTopicId__c, frm_Topic__c,  frm_MigrationFlag__c, LastModifiedDate, frm_CommentBodyValue__c '+ 
                f'FROM frm_Post__c WHERE frm_ExternalCommentId__c IN ({COMMENT_IDS})'
                }, keys = keys)
```

But I notice that the result only shows 250 records.
I check the same query with the **Query editor** and retrieve 629.

> Note: I check that the credentials are from the same org.

I would like to know what happened

Comment: Please [edit] to show us what `sf_api_call` does.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that I made the **GET call** retrieved an key with the name **[nextRecordsUrl](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/just-little-cold-here)** and the key **done** was in false. I have to create another call to retrieve the rest of the records but with the **nextRecordsURL endpoint** to retrieve the rest of them.

When the response doesn't show the key and the key **done** is in true, the records are completed.

Comment: You might evaluate using [`simple_salesforce`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce), which handles these semantics for you.